# Storing integers in char array and adding

Tags: c++, c

I have come to know that one can store digits from 0-255 in char data type. So, I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char num[4];
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;

    printf("Enter Four Digit Number\n");

    while(i<4)
    {
        scanf("%1d",&num[i]);
        i++;
    }

    sum=(int)num[0]+(int)num[1]+(int)num[2]+(int)num[3];

    printf("Sum of digits: %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

which seems to run correctly but as soon as I put the following code in while loop, the value of `i` changes to zero every time the loop reiterates and code breaks:

```
sum=sum+(int)(num[i]); i++;
```

I'm using code::blocks with MinGW compiler.

Comment: _'that one can store digits from 0-255 in char data type'_ A `uint8_t` is fine to do this?!?

Comment: It's unsigned char array, I guess; So 2^8=256?

Comment: You cannot use a pointer to `char` to store the result of the `%d` format; it expects a pointer to integer. Your `scanf` probably corrupts memory on the stack. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: The `char` type is not usnigned; it's signed on some platforms and unsigned on others. Better use `int` variables throughout your code when doing arithmetics and leave `char`s for character arrays.

Comment: Okay, I will convert the char to int. Thanks for help. :)

Comment: I tried to see what's going on with 'watches'. Numbers are being stored in format of "/002/000/001/004", when added using sum=(int)num[0]+(int)num[1]+(int)num[2]+(int)num[3]; Somehow, it works and gives 7. I think it's dark territory of compiler, should be left uncharted.

Comment: `x86` is little-endian, and you're using numbers less than 255, so it's probably storing the least significant byte "correctly" in each of your array elements, but the more significant bytes are all zero and are overwriting `sum` on each loop, since `sum` is defined immediately after `num`.

Comment: Dvorak, I have a question. Why? Why use something substandard when `int` is made and optimized for the purpose of arithmetic? I don't see a purpose, aside from novelty and creating code which is nigh impossible to debug without knowledge of how C compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Be VERY VERY careful when you use character types to store numbers.  The range of a `signed char` can vary depending on your compiler, and the operating system.  On most, the minimum value is -128 and the maximum value is 127.  On others it can differ.  This can become problematic when you expect the range to be from 0-255.  If you want to use a `char` to store numbers, use `unsigned char`, as it's range is 0-255.

Because the numeric representations of a character (signed, or unsigned) are not garunteed, I usually approach the problem by writing a function that uses an array to assign, and look up, the numeric values.  (but, I almost never do this, it's easier to use an integer...)

Answer (score -1):

if you want add the integer value into the particular index

```
char a[10];
int i=9;

a[2]=boost::lexical_cast<char>(i)
```

found this is the best way to convert char into int and vice-versa.

Comment: edited for the adding a integer into particular index value.

Answer (score -2):

This works fine for me.

```
while(i < 4){
  scanf("%1d", &num[i]);
  sum += (int)(num[i++]);
}
```

Comment: The question is not if he should use an unsigned byte for ffs.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with my compiler. I don't know why but value of i is assigned the value 0 as soon as this statement is encountered.